# Can't commit Xcode project with åäö in filename

Tags: xcode, git, commit

I can't commit when having a filename containing the letter 'Ö'. In this example my filename is 'Övning'. I get the following error when entering a commit message and pressing commit:

> error: pathspec '"O\314\210vning/MasterViewController.m"' did not
>   match any file(s) known to git.

I also get random crashed when opening the commit window.

Anyone else experiencing this?